# JS: Can't wrap all links into the <a> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to wrap all links in a string into the `<a>` tag using the following simple JS-code:

```js
var str = 'Foo https://example1.com bar foo https://www.example2.com bar https://example3.com/url';

var str = str.replace(/(.+)?(http|https)\:\/\/(\S+)(.+)?/g, '$1<a href="$2://$3" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$2://$3</a>$4');

console.log(str);
```

But only the last link is wrapped

How to wrap all the links?

ps. I know about a solution in PHP, but it doesn't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$&` **(whole match)**

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2I4Nur/3)

```js
var str = 'Foo https://example1.com bar foo https://www.example2.com bar https://example3.com/url';

var str = str.replace(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi, '<a href="$&" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$&</a>');

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: What does the `b` mean before `https` ?

Comment: `\b` is word boundary

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture everything before and after the URL. Replace will only replace the section that has been matched.

```js
var str = 'Foo https://example1.com bar foo https://www.example2.com bar https://example3.com/url';

var str = str.replace(/(http|https)\:\/\/(\S+)/g, '<a href="$1://$2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$1://$2</a>');

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set of functions i've been using to format text:

```js
/**
 * Adds anchor elements to all the links inside a string
 * @param {string} text text to be converted
 * @returns {string} converted text 
 */
function setLinks(text) {
  var regex = /(https?:[/]{0,2}|[w]{3}[.])[^ "'>]{1,}/g;
  text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  return text.replace(regex, addLink);
}

/**
 * Surrounds string in an anchor tag
 * @param {string} link url of link
 * @returns {string} 
 */
function addLink(link) {
  var descr = String(link).replace(/^(https?:[/]{0,2})?([w]{3}[.])?/, "www.");
  if (!/^https?:[/]{2}/.test(link)) link = `http://${link}`;
  return `<a href=${link} target="_blank">${descr}</a>`;
}

document.write(setLinks('Foo https://example1.com bar foo https://www.example2.com bar https://example3.com/url'));
```

Comment: +1 for HTML-encoding the content, which may help prevent XSS vulnerabilities. But you forgot to encode `&`. Before the first replace, you should have this statement: `text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");` This prevents the text 'print&copy' being rendered as 'printⒸ'

Comment: @RuudHelderman There are a couple of things that fall under that case. I only replaced the ones I dealt with while creating that script.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to handle other non matched parts in replace.

```js
var str = 'Foo https://example1.com bar foo https://www.example2.com bar https://example3.com/url';

var str = str.replace(/(http|https)\:\/\/(\S+)/g, '<a href="$&" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">$&</a>');

console.log(str);
```